# best way to synchronise method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a task management type application. So when someone completes the task the task creator emails a message with the task URL. I am using spring MVC to create this application. So now the problem is when two tasks are created  at almost the same time, the email for the 1st task I get the URL generated for 2nd task.

I wrote the following method to perform this functionality

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "commentTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public List<List<Task>> reply(@ModelAttribute Task task,@RequestParam ("parentId") long parentId,HttpSession session) {
    List<List<Task>> listTasks = null;

    taskEntryService.insertTask(task,session);

    listTasks = taskEntryService.selectAssignedTask(task.getAssignTo(), parentId);

    String taskurl = siteUrl + "showAssignedTask?assignto="+ task.getAssignTo() + "&taskId="+parentId; 

    if(task.getTaskUpdateEmailNotify().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

            try {

                if(task.getStatus() == 4){

                    String completedTaskBody = taskCompletedEmailBody(taskurl, task.getAssignToName(), task.getTaskTitle(), task.getAssignerName(), task.getSummary()); 

                    sendmailService.sendMail("no-reply@gmail.com", task.getTaskCreatorEmail(), "Your Task has been Completed", completedTaskBody);
            }
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    return listTasks;
}
```

So what is the best way to syncronize this method.

Please let me know if more detail is required

Comment: What is the type of `sendmailService`, and is the class thread-safe? Ditto for `taskEntryService`

Comment: How is this method invoked? Does the user click on a URL? Are you sure this method isn't getting invoked with the wrong `Task` (perhaps a bug in the front end)?

Comment: @EmilSit this method is when someone reply to the task created. So this method stores the value in database and send email to task creator. This happen only once to me when someone reply to task at same time otherwise its working fine.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot please find my updated code I am using jmail sender to send email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to synchronize access to this method would of course be to mark it as `synchronized` in the signature.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "commentTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public synchronized List<List<Task>> reply(@ModelAttribute Task task,
      @RequestParam ("parentId") long parentId,
      HttpSession session) {
```

It seems unlikely to me that synchronization here will solve your problem since the code does not seem like it has any particular race condition: it takes care to construct the full URL from the provided `Task` object. I suspect that somehow either your `Task` object is not thread-safe or that the wrong `parentId` is being passed in.

Comment: thanks for your response. how could I find that this method does not have any race condition. I  tried again by commenting the tasks at same time but this does not happen to me again but worrying me how the task data could swapped

Comment: You are not calling any `Task` mutators in this method (at least, assuming the `get` methods do not mutate), so it seems unlikely to me that any race is happening in this method.

Comment: Hi Emil, sorry for late response. I think you are right that my Task object is not thread safe. Could you please help me how can I make my Task object thread-safe

Comment: @user965884 You should ask a new question and include the code for your `Task` class and perhaps the relevant code that uses it. If you are happy with this answer, you could accept it.